# python3 and python2 compatibility choices

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am missing the point why Python3 has commands that are not compatible with Python2.

For example the command

> print 'hello'

does work in Python2 and not in Python3. Why?

I would expect Python3 to be compatible with Python2, the same as C#4 is compatible with C#2 for example.

Comment: Why *do* you expect Python 3 to be compatible with Python 2? All Python 2.x series releases are compatible, but Python 3.x was a *major version change*, and is **not** compatible with 2.x. Within 3.x releases are compatible.

Comment: The major version number changed **because** the language changed in incompatible ways.

Comment: I expect the compatibility because I come from the C# world and for me it is normal to use C# 2.0 (delegates) features and C# 4.0 (dynamic) in the same program. For example I would like python3 to accept both print 'hello'   and print('hello'), but perhaps this is not compatible with the philosophy of the language (?).

Comment: Always do in Python 3 if you are starting new.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Not necessarily. Not all modules are python 3 compatible

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9066956/1931274

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am missing the point why Python3 has commands are not compatible with Python2.

Because Python 3 is not the same language as Python 2.

Python releases **normally** are mostly backwards compatible with previous versions; Python 2.7 is largely backwards compatible with Python 2.6.

However, from the start, Python 3 (or 3000 as its design project originally codenamed) was specifically **different**. Quoting from [one of the design documents](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3002/):

> Python 3000 will introduce a number of backwards-incompatible changes to Python, mainly to streamline the language and to remove some previous design mistakes.)

So, Python 3 is not backwards compatible to correct specific errors in the language that could *not* be corrected with backwards compatible changes.

The use of a statement to write to `stdout` instead of a function is one of those changes; `print` has been replaced by a function `print()`.

Different language and software projects use different standards for what their version numbers mean. Python sticks to the major-minor-micro scheme; releases within the same major number are largely backwards compatible, releases within the same minor number only contain bug fixes. See the [Python version number FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#how-does-the-python-version-numbering-scheme-work):

> Python versions are numbered `A.B.C` or `A.B`. `A` is the major version number – it is only incremented for really major changes in the language. `B` is the minor version number, incremented for less earth-shattering changes. `C` is the micro-level – it is incremented for each bugfix release. See [PEP 6](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0006/) for more information about bugfix releases.

Python is also quite a bit older than C#. Python development started in 1989, and version 2.0 came out in 2000. C# on the other hand has only been around since 2002; perhaps in another decade or so it too will see a backwards-incompatible change.

Comment: Also, [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#rationale) lists five specific reasons for changing `print` to a function.

Answer (score 3):

Because in Python 2, `print` is a statement. But [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is now a function in Python 3. However, `print(...)` is still valid syntax in Python 2, and you can also do `from __future__ import print_function` to get Python 3's print function in Python 2.

Don't expect python 3 to be compatible with 2; [there are many other changes](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). For example, `reduce()` was removed, and most built-in functions now return generators that once returned lists (eg `map()`, `zip()`, and `filter()`).

Comment: This does not answer *why* Python 3 is incompatible with Python 2. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters There really is no answer to that. Gotta ask GVR himself :P

Comment: There is an answer to that; I'll post it shortly. The community provided information on that.

Answer (score 0):

python3 has a tool named "2to3". This tool will help you to convert python2.x source code to python3.x source code.
Read the manual http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: While this is true... it doesn't answer the OPs question of why some changes to Python3 are not backwards compatible...