# Failure to install ndg-httpsclient or maybe I'm doing the solution wrong

Tags: python, wpf, ironpython

I'm new to python and have a little experience with VS, C# and WPF.

My question might seem similar to some asked questions, but I tried several of the suggested solutions (that worked for others), and yet it doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to build a simple WPF application that will send http requests.
The solution structure is as follows:

```
Solution MyApp
   Project 1 <This is the startup project>
      GUImodul.py
      queryStringBuilder.py
      <This project uses IronPython env for the WPF support>
   Project 2
      QuerySender.py (includes two classes)
      <This project uses Python 3.4 env, only in this one I managed installing the "requests" package which I need for sending the query>
```

When I try to run this I get an error "No module named ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification", even though I only import from project 2 a class that doesn't contain any import from "requests" (it only creates an instance of the other class there that does have such import).

When I try to install ndg-httpsclient using pip, I get "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1".

Things I tried so far:

1. Adding "-X:FullFrames" to the debug properties of both projects
2. (re)installing steuptools with from ez_setup.zip
3. As said - ndg-httpsclient is installed for Python34
4. Using the "import requests" command only within the class NOT imported to Project1 (the one with IronPython env)
5. Tried installing a newer(?) version of urllib3

So...
I just might be doing something fundamentally wrong in this solution, which in this case I wish someone to help me understand what it is.

Otherwise, any idea what can I try next to make this thing work?

Comment: Note ndg-httpsclient now supports Python 3 as of version 0.4.0. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, though I already finished the project I was working on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the fine print, [`ndg-httpsclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ndg-httpsclient#downloads) is incompatible with Python 3, as it was developed for Python2.7 . That's probabably the root cause.

RE: [Why is Python 3.0 not backward compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066956/why-is-python-3-0-not-backward-compatible)

Comment: Hmm... guess that's the major part of the problem.
Interesting though is that within the console of Python 3.4 I do manage to get that piece of "requests"-dependant code running (including importing the pkg).

Comment: I'm going to try this solution again with IronPython 2.7 or just Python 2.7.

Comment: So... my project shifted a bit, so the use of WPF GUI became unnecessary. However, trying to use the "requests" packages' functions did work within the python 3.4 console, which was confusing and seemed a bit odd, but not impossible of course.
Long story short, I:
1. Installed python 2.7 (now having python 2.7, 3.4 and IronPython 2.7)
2. Started a new solution with python 2.7 as the environment
3. Installed "requests"
And finally it all works!

Comment: Release 0.4.0 - Made dual compatible with Python 2 / 3.