# random.randint shows different output in Python 2.x and Python 3.x with same seed

Tags: python

I am porting the application from python 2 to python 3 and encountered the following problem: `random.randint` returns different result according to used Python version. So

```
import random
random.seed(1)
result = random.randint(1, 100)
```

On Python 2.x result will be 14 and on Python 3.x: 18

Unfortunately, I need to have the same output on python3 to have backward compatibility of service.

Now I have only working idea of usage `subprocess` module from Python 3.x to execute Python 2.x code

```
result = subprocess.check_output(
    '''python2 -c "import random; random.seed('%s'); print(random.randint(1, 100))"''' % seed,
    shell=True
 )
```

But such an approach is slower approx. in 1000 times than execute just `random.randint(1, 100)`.

Maybe there are other approaches to do this?

Comment: Closely related: [Difference between Python 2 and 3 for shuffle with a given seed](//stackoverflow.com/q/38943038)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer!

Sparky05 give interesting idea and was near with `int(1+99*random.random())`.

But the right answer is

```
random.seed(seed, version=1)
int(random.random() * 100) + 1
```

in Python 3.x

Works in the same way like

```
random.seed(seed)
random.randint(1, 100)
```

in Python 2.x

Answer (score 9):

The difference is caused by two things:

1. You should use `random.seed(42, version=1)`
2. In python 3.2 there was a change to `random.randrange`, which is called by `random.randint` and probably add to above [issue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

So use something like:

```
try: random.seed(42, version=1)  # Python 3
except TypeError: random.seed(42)  # Python 2
```

and `int(1+random.random()*99)`.

### More detail

Backward compatibility was on purpose dropped with the change of `randrange`, see the original [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue9025).

See this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pythontips/comments/5pp5mz/the_random_module_with_the_same_seed_produces_a/) post.

If possible use `numpy.random`like is proposed in the reddit post.

Use of `random.seed(42, version=1)` as described in the  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#bookkeeping-functions) will cause `random.random()` to deliver the same result but give a different result for `random.randint(1,100)` (because in python 3.2 some problem with the old implementation was fixed). You may opt to only rely on something like `int(1+random.random()*99)`.

(Python 2 will run out of support very [soon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), [soon2](https://github.com/python/devguide/pull/344) or [here](https://pythonclock.org). If possible check, if backward compatibility is really needed.)

My current tests:

```
import random 

try: random.seed(42, version=1)  # Python 3
except TypeError: random.seed(42)  # Python 2
print(random.random())
print(int(1+99*random.random()))
print(random.randint(1,99))
```

Results on Python 2

```
0.639426798458
3
28
```

and Python 3

```
0.6394267984578837
3
36
```

Comment: Hi. Your answer with `np.random` will be valid if I don't have an existing running application with the usage of `random.randint`. The problem now is backward compatibility of an existing application. Same with `random.random()` I saw that this works in the same way on py2 and 3. But in my application code, I have `random.randint`

Comment: After some research it looks like there was some changes to ```random.randint```. I don't see a way to avoid different results, if you call this function. You could replace this function with your own implementation, which only uses ```random.random```

Comment: I've found the issue, which caused the changes of randrange and added it to the above post.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which version to use for the seed: `random.seed(1, version=1)`. However, as stated by Sparky05, you are probably better off using `numpy.random` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Functions which emulate `random.seed(a=None)` and `random.randint(a, b)` for `python 3` and `python 2`:

```python
import random


def seed(a=None):
    try:  # Python3
        random.seed(a, version=1)
    except TypeError:  # Python2
        random.seed(a)


def randint(a, b):
    return int(random.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a
```

Use:

```python
seed(1)
result = randint(1, 100)
```