# Parsing Event Information Table files

Tags: python, dvb

My dreambox compatible video recorder stores event information table ".eit" files with every recording. I'd like to work with this information to rearrange my recordings.

A similar question came up in http://www.i-have-a-dreambox.com/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=186234&sid=3b36acb1ba62e4724cb47216ce08a564

The format seems to be a binary format as outlined in:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Information_Table
and

http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300400_300499/300468/01.14.01_60/en_300468v011401p.pdf

**I am now looking for a parser for such files. Where could I find one that works with files and does not assume a broadcast stream as input?**

**What did i try so far?**

I searched the web and found the following links and pointers:

There seems to be a java library

https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/jsr927/javax/tv/service/guide/ProgramEvent.html

which is part of the JSR 927  https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=927
specification.

As it looks this libary is only available for Java-ME see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_TV

If found some dvb related EIT code snippets e.g.

https://github.com/jinfeng-geeya/3202C/blob/master/SRC/lib/libdvb/libepg/eit_parser.c

or

http://linuxtv.org/docs/libdvbv5/eit_8h.html

as part of the Kamaelia DVB Tools Project http://www.kamaelia.org/Developers/Projects/DVBTools.html there seems to be a python solution:

http://pydoc.net/Python/Kamaelia/0.6.0/Kamaelia.Device.DVB.Parse.ParseEventInformationTable/

The closest I found so far was from a hint athttp://forums.openpli.org/topic/29141-eit-file-format/ which points to:
https://github.com/betonme/e2openplugin-EnhancedMovieCenter/blob/master/src/EitSupport.py

Currently I am pursuing to go from this Open Source Python Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python script that seems to be a valid start.
It's available as opensource at https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/eitparser where you'll find the latest python3 compatible version and documentation.

When you call it with

```
python EitParser.py SomeEitFile
```

it will print out the name and description of the eit file.

Add you language codes as you need e.g. from https://github.com/libo/Enigma2/blob/master/lib/python/Tools/ISO639.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8
#
# EitSupport
# Copyright (C) 2011 betonme
# Copyright (C) 2016 Wolfgang Fahl
# 
# This EITParser is based on:
# https://github.com/betonme/e2openplugin-EnhancedMovieCenter/blob/master/src/EitSupport.py
#
# In case of reuse of this source code please do not remove this copyright.
#
#   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#   (at your option) any later version.
#
#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#   GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#   For more information on the GNU General Public License see:
#   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

import os
import struct
import time

from datetime import datetime

#from Components.config import config
#from Components.Language import language
#from EMCTasker import emcDebugOut
#from IsoFileSupport import IsoSupport
#from MetaSupport import getInfoFile

#def crc32(data):
#   poly = 0x4c11db7
#   crc = 0xffffffffL
#   for byte in data:
#       byte = ord(byte)
#       for bit in range(7,-1,-1):  # MSB to LSB
#           z32 = crc>>31    # top bit
#           crc = crc << 1
#           if ((byte>>bit)&1) ^ z32:
#               crc = crc ^ poly
#           crc = crc & 0xffffffffL
#   return crc

decoding_charSpecHR = {u'Ć': u'\u0106', u'æ': u'\u0107', u'®': u'\u017D', u'¾': u'\u017E', u'©': u'\u0160', u'¹': u'\u0161', u'Č': u'\u010C', u'è': u'\u010D', u'ð': u'\u0111'}

decoding_charSpecCZSK = {u'Ï'+u'C': u'Č',u'Ï'+u'E': u'Ě',u'Ï'+u'L': u'Ľ',u'Ï'+u'N': u'Ň',u'Ï'+u'R': u'Ř',u'Ï'+u'S': u'Š',u'Ï'+u'T': u'Ť',u'Ï'+u'Z': u'Ž',u'Ï'+u'c': u'č',u'Ï'+u'd': u'ď',u'Ï'+u'e': u'ě',u'Ï'+u'l': u'ľ', u'Ï'+u'n': u'ň',
u'Ï'+u'r': u'ř',u'Ï'+u's': u'š',u'Ï'+u't': u'ť',u'Ï'+u'z': u'ž',u'Ï'+u'D': u'Ď',u'Â'+u'A': u'Á',u'Â'+u'E': u'É',u'Â'+u'I': u'Í',u'Â'+u'O': u'Ó',u'Â'+u'U': u'Ú',u'Â'+u'a': u'á',u'Â'+u'e': u'é',u'Â'+u'i': u'í',u'Â'+u'o': u'ó',
u'Â'+u'u': u'ú',u'Â'+u'y': u'ý',u'Ã'+u'o': u'ô',u'Ã'+u'O': u'Ô',u'Ê'+u'u': u'ů',u'Ê'+u'U': u'Ů',u'È'+u'A': u'Ä',u'È'+u'E': u'Ë',u'È'+u'I': u'Ï',u'È'+u'O': u'Ö',u'È'+u'U': u'Ü',u'È'+u'Y': u'Ÿ',u'È'+u'a': u'ä',u'È'+u'e': u'ë',
u'È'+u'i': u'ï',u'È'+u'o': u'ö',u'È'+u'u': u'ü',u'È'+u'y': u'ÿ'}

def convertCharSpecHR(text):
    for i, j in decoding_charSpecHR.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

def convertCharSpecCZSK(text):
    for i, j in decoding_charSpecCZSK.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

def parseMJD(MJD):
    # Parse 16 bit unsigned int containing Modified Julian Date,
    # as per DVB-SI spec
    # returning year,month,day
    YY = int( (MJD - 15078.2) / 365.25 )
    MM = int( (MJD - 14956.1 - int(YY*365.25) ) / 30.6001 )
    D  = MJD - 14956 - int(YY*365.25) - int(MM * 30.6001)
    K=0
    if MM == 14 or MM == 15: K=1

    return (1900 + YY+K), (MM-1-K*12), D

def unBCD(byte):
    return (byte>>4)*10 + (byte & 0xf)


#from Tools.ISO639 import LanguageCodes
# -*- coding: iso-8859-2 -*-
LanguageCodes = { }
LanguageCodes["deu"] = LanguageCodes["ger"] = LanguageCodes["de"] = ("German", "Germanic")
LanguageCodes["fra"] = LanguageCodes["fre"] = LanguageCodes["fr"] = ("French", "Romance")


def language_iso639_2to3(alpha2):
    ret = alpha2
    if alpha2 in LanguageCodes:
        language = LanguageCodes[alpha2]
        for alpha, name in LanguageCodes.items():
            if name == language:
                if len(alpha) == 3:
                    return alpha
    return ret
#TEST
#print LanguageCodes["sv"]
#print language_iso639_2to3("sv")


# Eit File support class
# Description
# http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Information_Table
class EitList():

    EIT_SHORT_EVENT_DESCRIPTOR      = 0x4d
    EIT_EXTENDED_EVENT_DESCRIPOR    =   0x4e

    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.eit_file = None

        #TODO
        # The dictionary implementation could be very slow
        self.eit = {}
        self.iso = None

        self.__newPath(path)
        self.__readEitFile()

    def __newPath(self, path):
        name = None
        if path:
            if self.eit_file != path:
                self.eit_file = path

    def __mk_int(self, s):
        return int(s) if s else 0

    def __toDate(self, d, t):
        if d and t:
            #TODO Is there another fast and safe way to get the datetime
            try:
                return datetime(int(d[0]), int(d[1]), int(d[2]), int(t[0]), int(t[1]))
            except ValueError:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    ##############################################################################
    ## Get Functions
    def getEitsid(self):
        return self.eit.get('service', "") #TODO

    def getEitTsId(self):
        return self.eit.get('transportstream', "") #TODO

    def getEitWhen(self):
        return self.eit.get('when', "")

    def getEitStartDate(self):
        return self.eit.get('startdate', "")

    def getEitStartTime(self):
        return self.eit.get('starttime', "")

    def getEitDuration(self):
        return self.eit.get('duration', "")

    def getEitName(self):
        return self.eit.get('name', "").strip()

    def getEitDescription(self):
        return self.eit.get('description', "").strip()

    # Wrapper
    def getEitShortDescription(self):
        return self.getEitName()

    def getEitExtendedDescription(self):
        return self.getEitDescription()

    def getEitLengthInSeconds(self):
        length = self.eit.get('duration', "")
        #TODO Is there another fast and safe way to get the length
        if len(length)>2:
            return self.__mk_int((length[0]*60 + length[1])*60 + length[2])
        elif len(length)>1:
            return self.__mk_int(length[0]*60 + length[1])
        else:
            return self.__mk_int(length)

    def getEitDate(self):
        return self.__toDate(self.getEitStartDate(), self.getEitStartTime())

    ##############################################################################
    ## File IO Functions
    def __readEitFile(self):
        data = ""
        path = self.eit_file
        
        #lang = language.getLanguage()[:2]
        lang = language_iso639_2to3( "de" )
        #print lang + str(path)
    
        if path and os.path.exists(path):
                #print "Reading Event Information Table " + str(path)

                # Read data from file
                # OE1.6 with Pyton 2.6
                #with open(self.eit_file, 'r') as file: lines = file.readlines()
                f = None
                try:
                    f = open(path, 'rb')
                    #lines = f.readlines()
                    data = f.read()
                except Exception, e:
                    emcDebugOut("[META] Exception in readEitFile: " + str(e))
                finally:
                    if f is not None:
                        f.close()

                # Parse the data
                if data and 12 <= len(data):
                    # go through events
                    pos = 0
                    e = struct.unpack(">HHBBBBBBH", data[pos:pos+12])
                    event_id = e[0]
                    date     = parseMJD(e[1])                         # Y, M, D
                    time     = unBCD(e[2]), unBCD(e[3]), unBCD(e[4])  # HH, MM, SS
                    duration = unBCD(e[5]), unBCD(e[6]), unBCD(e[7])  # HH, MM, SS
                    running_status  = (e[8] & 0xe000) >> 13
                    free_CA_mode    = e[8] & 0x1000
                    descriptors_len = e[8] & 0x0fff

                    if running_status in [1,2]:
                        self.eit['when'] = "NEXT"
                    elif running_status in [3,4]:
                        self.eit['when'] = "NOW"

                    self.eit['startdate'] = date
                    self.eit['starttime'] = time
                    self.eit['duration'] = duration

                    pos = pos + 12
                    short_event_descriptor = []
                    short_event_descriptor_multi = []
                    extended_event_descriptor = []
                    extended_event_descriptor_multi = []
                    component_descriptor = []
                    content_descriptor = []
                    linkage_descriptor = []
                    parental_rating_descriptor = []
                    endpos = len(data) - 1
                    while pos < endpos:
                        rec = ord(data[pos])
                        length = ord(data[pos+1]) + 2
                        if rec == 0x4D:
                            descriptor_tag = ord(data[pos+1])
                            descriptor_length = ord(data[pos+2])
                            ISO_639_language_code = str(data[pos+3:pos+5])
                            event_name_length = ord(data[pos+5])
                            short_event_description = data[pos+6:pos+6+event_name_length]
                            if ISO_639_language_code == lang:
                                short_event_descriptor.append(short_event_description)
                            short_event_descriptor_multi.append(short_event_description)
                            
                        elif rec == 0x4E:
                            ISO_639_language_code = str(data[pos+3:pos+5])
                            extended_event_description = ""
                            extended_event_description_multi = ""
                            for i in range (pos+8,pos+length):
                                if str(ord(data[i]))=="138":
                                    extended_event_description += '\n'
                                    extended_event_description_multi += '\n'
                                else:
                                    if data[i]== '\x10' or data[i]== '\x00' or  data[i]== '\x02':
                                        pass
                                    else:
                                        extended_event_description += data[i]
                                        extended_event_description_multi += data[i]
                            if ISO_639_language_code == lang:
                                extended_event_descriptor.append(extended_event_description)
                            extended_event_descriptor_multi.append(extended_event_description)
                        elif rec == 0x50:
                            component_descriptor.append(data[pos+8:pos+length])
                        elif rec == 0x54:
                            content_descriptor.append(data[pos+8:pos+length])
                        elif rec == 0x4A:
                            linkage_descriptor.append(data[pos+8:pos+length])
                        elif rec == 0x55:
                            parental_rating_descriptor.append(data[pos+2:pos+length])
                        else:
                            #print "unsopported descriptor: %x %x" %(rec, pos + 12)
                            #print data[pos:pos+length]
                            pass
                        pos += length

                    # Very bad but there can be both encodings
                    # User files can be in cp1252
                    # Is there no other way?
                    if short_event_descriptor:
                        short_event_descriptor = "".join(short_event_descriptor)
                    else:
                        short_event_descriptor = "".join(short_event_descriptor_multi)
                    if short_event_descriptor:
                        #try:
                        #   short_event_descriptor = short_event_descriptor.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")
                        #except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        #   pass
                        try:
                            short_event_descriptor.decode('utf-8')
                        except UnicodeDecodeError:
                            try:
                                short_event_descriptor = short_event_descriptor.decode("cp1252").encode("utf-8")
                            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                                # do nothing, otherwise cyrillic wont properly displayed
                                #short_event_descriptor = short_event_descriptor.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")
                                pass
                            if (lang == "cs") or (lang == "sk"):
                                short_event_descriptor = str(convertCharSpecCZSK(short_event_descriptor))
                            if (lang == "hr"):
                                short_event_descriptor = str(convertCharSpecHR(short_event_descriptor))
                    self.eit['name'] = short_event_descriptor

                    # Very bad but there can be both encodings
                    # User files can be in cp1252
                    # Is there no other way?
                    if extended_event_descriptor:
                        extended_event_descriptor = "".join(extended_event_descriptor)
                    else:
                        extended_event_descriptor = "".join(extended_event_descriptor_multi)
                    if extended_event_descriptor:
                        #try:
                        #   extended_event_descriptor = extended_event_descriptor.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")
                        #except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        #   pass
                        try:
                            extended_event_descriptor.decode('utf-8')
                        except UnicodeDecodeError:
                            try:
                                extended_event_descriptor = extended_event_descriptor.decode("cp1252").encode("utf-8")
                            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                                # do nothing, otherwise cyrillic wont properly displayed
                                #extended_event_descriptor = extended_event_descriptor.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")
                                pass
                            if (lang == "cs") or (lang == "sk"):
                                extended_event_descriptor = str(convertCharSpecCZSK(extended_event_descriptor))
                            if (lang == "hr"):
                                extended_event_descriptor = str(convertCharSpecHR(extended_event_descriptor))
                    self.eit['description'] = extended_event_descriptor

                else:
                    # No date clear all
                    self.eit = {}

"""Module docstring.

Read Eit File and show the information.
"""
import sys
import getopt

def readeit(eitfile):
    eitlist=EitList(eitfile)
    print eitlist.getEitName();
    print eitlist.getEitStartDate();
    print eitlist.getEitDescription();
    
     
def main():
    # parse command line options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "h", ["help"])
    except getopt.error, msg:
        print msg
        print "for help use --help"
        sys.exit(2)
    # process options
    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            print __doc__
            sys.exit(0)
    # process arguments
    for arg in args:
        readeit(arg) # process() is defined elsewhere

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 3.5 years into the future, please mind that this code syntax is [not valid anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067012/1282023) for Python v3+. You should however be able to [convert it automatically](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).

Comment: see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/eitparser/commit/129c65707bffa334f60259e3db67f77e54223f78