# how to resolve Cmake implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type

Tags: python, visual-studio, cmake, caffe

I am trying to set up caffe on my laptop and when I run the `scripts\build_win.cmd` command I get the follow errors:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Anaconda3/python.exe (found suitable version 
"3.7.3", minimum required is "2.7")
CMake Error at cmake/WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake:40 (message):
  Could not find url for MSVC version = 1900 and Python version = 3.7.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/p12ai/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: Configure failed
```

I currently have VS 2015 installed and I got all of the python packets and C++ packets installed that it provided. I have the newest conda installed with python 3.7
Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?
Please let me know if there any files or other details you would like to know.

Comment: Are you asking about the cause of the warning (implied by your question title) or do you want help to resolve the error (implied by your statements on the installed tools)? Please edit your question to make clear, what you are asking about. Btw. even though, Python 3.7 has a higher version number, it's not necessarily suitable to resolve dependency on Python 2.7, since [Python 3 is not backwards compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067012/579698)

Comment: @StanleyF. I am assuming that if someone says what is causing it, then it will help me figure out how to resolve it, but mainly I want to know how to resolve it.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to care about this message, it is just a warning and can be ignored. If you want to have a closer look on it, open the `cmake/Misc.cmake` file and see what line 33 says. If you post this part of the file, you may get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @StanleyF.: Here is the line: `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE CACHE BOOLEAN "Use link paths for shared library rpath")` (taken from the repo https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Misc.cmake#L32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not sure why it wasnt working, but for some reason after I reinstalled anaconda with Python 3.5, and restarted the computer, I no longer had this issue. I know that caffe needs either python 3.5 or 2.7, so I am guessing that was part of it, although I had this isue when I had this version of anaconda before. I am guessing it didnt work then since I did not restart the computer